# Are these two forms of the sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

*An European thinks that India is still the land of snake charmers.*

*Europeans think that India is still the land of snake charmers.*

Are both of the above sentences grammatically correct or is one of them wrong?

Also, is using "the" correct (in the first sentence)?

Comment: If you are referring to all Europeans, then the latter is your choice.

Comment: "An European" should be "A European" because it has a "Y" sound.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. Otherwise is the first sentence correct even if it does not refer to a particular European ?

Comment: Perhaps "**a** land of snake charmers", not "**the** land ..."

Comment: Otherwise I would say the sentences mean the same ... "a (typical) European" means "Europeans". I prefer the second.

Comment: @WeatherVane From [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=india+the+land+of+snake+charmers&oq=india+the+land+of+snake+c&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.10726j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) google search it seems "the" is fine. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Your googling shows both! But "the land" has a different meaning from "a land". The former suggests there is (was) only one land of snake charmers.

Comment: @WeatherVane Actually that is true. India was historically called the "the land of snake charmers". I don't know any other country which is referred by the same.

Comment: Please wait for at least 24 hours before excepting an answer. Read [this](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) if you want to know why it is wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first original sentence "*An European thinks that India is still the land of snake charmers*" is definitely wrong because of the article used at the beginning, since in the word "**European**" is pronounced [**jʊə.rəˈpiː.ən**] and should be preceded with "**a**" and not "**an**" according to the rules. The vowel "**E**" here sounds like a consonant.

> Use A before words such as "European" or "university" which sound like they start with a consonant even if the first letter is a vowel. ([EnglishPage.com](https://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-vs-an.htm))

"**The**" is correct in "***the*** land of snake charmers" still "**a**" wouldn't be a mistake either.

Comment: Yes. That was pointed out in the comments. BTW is "the land of snake charmers" correct or we should replace "the" with "a" ?

Comment: @Blue Since that wasn't in your question. "The" is definitely correct here, although "a" won't be a mistake.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the main point of the question, which surely is whether the singular or the plural should be used to generalise.

Comment: @James The main point of the question is "*are they both **grammatically correct**?*". My answer says they are!

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct.

If you are speaking of European people in general, then the desired meaning is the second. You should use "Europeans".

We can use "A" to mean "one". For example, you could write "A European visitor might think India is exotic, but he will soon find much that is familiar". In this sentence we introduce a single person.

Your first sentence is awkward. Note how I've used "might" in my example, since while I can talk about Europeans in general. It is odd to say "A European thinks India is exotic" since it supposes that this is true for every single European. It also implies (by using the present tense) that this one European always thinks this. The first sentence is an example of good grammar, but bad English.

Also note, people rarely like to be generalised! Europe is a region with over half a billion people. Many European people were born in India, or come from Indian families. Try to use an adjective not a noun for people. "European people" not "Europeans", and soften the generalisation. "Some European people might think ..."

Both "the land of snake charmers" and "a land of snake charmers" are correct. The difference is whether you understand there to be only one such land (the normal a/the distinction).

Answer (score 0):

> An European thinks that India is still the land of snake charmers."

This sentence implies that a specific European individual holds this belief about India. Using "the" in this sentence is correct. It is important to note that the use of "an" before "European" is nonstandard. Most native English speakers would use "a" instead of "an" in this case, as "European" starts with a consonant sound: "*A European thinks that India is still the land of snake charmers.*"

> "Europeans think that India is still the land of snake charmers."

This sentence suggests that Europeans, in general, hold this belief about India. Here, the statement is a generalization.

Comment: Both sentences are generalizations.  "A European" refers to anyone, not a specific person.